# Interpretation of Psychopy/iohub Tobii Gaze Data

Tags: psychopy, eye-tracking

I have recorded gaze data using Psychopy/iohub and a Tobii TX300 eye tracker. Loading the hdf5 file shows the following entries in a BinocularEyeSampleEvent:

```
['experiment_id', 'session_id', 'device_id',  'event_id', 'type', 'device_time', 'logged_time', 'time', 'confidence_interval', 'delay', 'filter_id', 'left_gaze_x', 'left_gaze_y', 'left_gaze_z', 'left_eye_cam_x',  'left_eye_cam_y', 'left_eye_cam_z', 'left_angle_x', 'left_angle_y', 'left_raw_x', 'left_raw_y', 'left_pupil_measure1', 'left_pupil_measure1_type', 'left_pupil_measure2', 'left_pupil_measure2_type', 'left_ppd_x', 'left_ppd_y', 'left_velocity_x', 'left_velocity_y', 'left_velocity_xy' 'right_gaze_x', 'right_gaze_y', 'right_gaze_z', 'right_eye_cam_x', 'right_eye_cam_y', 'right_eye_cam_z', 'right_angle_x', 'right_angle_y', 'right_raw_x', 'right_raw_y', 'right_pupil_measure1', 'right_pupil_measure1_type', 'right_pupil_measure2', 'right_pupil_measure2_type', 'right_ppd_x', 'right_ppd_y', 'right_velocity_x', 'right_velocity_y', 'right_velocity_xy', 'status']
```

They are different from those described in the official [documentation](http://www.isolver-solutions.com/iohubdocs/iohub/api_and_manual/device_details/eyetracker_interface/Tobii_Implementation_Notes.html), so where can I find an accurate description of what the data means? For instance, what is PPD, what does a measure type '77' mean or what unit was the velocity measured in? Is there an up-to-date documentation somehwere?
...and, maybe most importantly, which of the entries represent the point of gaze on the screen (taking the calibration into account)?

Comment: The "official documentation" linked to is now officially out-of-date. The now-official ioHub docs are supposed to be hosted at the PsychoPy site, BUT unfortunately they are not as complete as the old ones and certainly don't address this. Will ask Sol Simpson if he can answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found all the answers in this [well commented code on github](https://github.com/psychopy/versions/blob/master/psychopy/iohub/devices/eyetracker/eye_events.py).
The constants (like Type 77) can be found [here](https://github.com/psychopy/versions/blob/master/psychopy/iohub/constants.py)
Maybe the PsychoPy devolpers want to link this file in the documentation...?

Comment: Is this solution also available for [Tobii Eye Tracker 4C](https://gaming.tobii.com/product/tobii-eye-tracker-4c/)?